# How do I get a JLabel to show over a JButton?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, jbutton, jlabel

I have a JLabel that is ontop of a JButton, but it will not show up ontop. When the code for the JButton is commented out, the JLabel is shown, meaning that it is there but is on the bottom. Is there a way to show the JLabel ontop of the JButton?

Any help would be awesome. Thank you!

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class TestingLabelsOverButtons extends JFrame
    {
        public static void main (String []args)
        {   
            new TestingLabelsOverButtons();
        }

        public TestingLabelsOverButtons()
        {
            super();
            setSize(500,500);
            Container c = getContentPane();
            c.setLayout(null);
            c.setBackground(Color.white);

            JButton button = new JButton("Button");
            button.setBounds(0,0,500,500);
            c.add(button);

            JLabel label = new JLabel("Label");
            label.setBounds(0,0,500,500);
            c.add(label);

          setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

For clarification, I need this for my game where when the button is clicked, a JLabel will be shown ontop of the button to display a "score" that is added. In my game, the JLabel will be a smaller square than the JButton, so the JButton still needs to be visible.

Comment: *"Why?"* - `JButton` supports both text and icons, so what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: 1) Perhaps this actually needs a tooltip.  2) `setLayout(null);` Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or combinations of them, along with layout padding & borders for white space.

Comment: Your method setBounds() are both pointing to the same position..

Comment: For clarification, I need this for my game where when the button is clicked, a JLabel will be shown ontop of the button to display a "score" that is added. In my game, the JLabel will be a smaller square than the JButton, so the JButton still needs to be visible.

Comment: why not "JButton button = new JButton("Label");" ?

Comment: The JButton already displays an icon and background. The popup JLabel will not encompass the whole area that the button takes, so the icon on the JButton should still be visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swing paint components based on the ZOrder of the component. Basically the last component added is painted first.

So you could achieve what you want by doing:

```
c.add(button);
c.add(label);
```

Although, I agree with the comments. What are you trying to do? There is probably a better solution. It is almost never a good idea to be using setBounds() to position and size a component.

> I need this for my game where when the button is clicked, a JLabel will be shown ontop of the button to display a "score" that is added.

If you are going to force the user to click a button to display the score then you should probably be using a `JOptionPane` to display the label. Otherwise how will the label disappear? Forcing the user to click on the same button is not a very good UI.

Comment: I have a JPanel that is a grid of 16 JButtons (4 by 4). When a score needs to be added ,a popup will apear in the middle of the panel that displays the added score. The popup will be displayed on top of the middle 4 buttons, so I want it to be visible on top of the buttons (but the buttons should still be seen). I cannot seem to be able to do this, even if the label is added after the buttons.

Comment: The popup is created when the score is updated, and a timer is used to call upon a different method to remove the JLabel. It is more of a graphical update than a optionpane where the user has to click "Ok".

Comment: Read the Swing tutorial on [Using Root Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html). You could use a Glass Pane for this or maybe a JLayeredPane is better.

Comment: I don't have a background with glasspanes or anything, but I wish to do this in the easiest way possible. All of these components are part of a jpanel which is located on a jframe. I want to show the label over the buttons on the jpanel.